# Correctness, Possibility of adding dummy row to force FK working

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, database-schema

I have **OutputInvoiceDetails** and **InputInvoicesDetails** reference to **InputDetailedItemsDetails**.
- I have two categories of Items : **Detailed** items and **Global** items.
 - **InputDetailedItemsDetails** holds details about an Item of type **Detailed**.
 - My problem is that  Global Items do not have SerialNumber etc so they are not concerned by **DetailedItemsDetails** Table.

I felt into similar situation several times so I want to know in this case : 
 Is this schema correct ?
 Do I need to add a dummy row for Global items ? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended-up to invert the relation between InputInvoicesDetails and InputDetailedItemsDetails and remove other FKs. The problem has been solved. I really want to know how to solve this kind of situations.